# How can I get the role of an element through the evt object? Or any other distinguishable properties really

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, dom-events

Have a simple onClick event which I would like to see the role of the clicked element. The whole reason for this, is that I have an onClick event on my div that is interfearing with one of its children buttons. I need separate behaviors if the click is on the button within the div or elsewhere within the div.

Here is a sample of what I'm trying to go for:

```js
const App = () => {

  const onClickDiv = (evt) => {
    if (evt.target.role === 'dropdown') {
      console.warn('clicked on dropdown button. Do something different.')  
    } else {
      console.warn('clicked on div, but not on dropdown button')
    }
    
  }

  const onClickDropdownButton = () => {
    console.log('do stuff with dropdown button')
  }


  return (
    <div style={{ border: 'red solid 1px' }} onClick={onClickDiv}>
        My clickable div
        <div>
          <button onClick={onClickDropdownButton} role="dropdown">Dropdown Button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Take note that any other check works too. I just need figure out a way to know that the user clicked on the Dropdown button within the div as opposed to elsewhere in that same div.

Comment: What about adding a name prop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag works, I believe other props also work

```
const onClickDiv = (evt) => {
    if (evt.target.tagName === "BUTTON") {
      console.warn("clicked on dropdown button. Do something different.");
    } else {
      console.warn("clicked on div, but not on dropdown button");
    }
  };
```

Name:

```
if (evt.target.name === "dropBtn") {
  console.warn("clicked on dropdown button. Do something different.");
} else {
  console.warn("clicked on div, but not on dropdown button");
}
  };
```

But that requires it to be added on the html

```
<div
  name="dropDiv"
  style={{ border: "red solid 1px" }}
  onClick={onClickDiv}
>
  My clickable div
  <div>
    <button name="dropBtn" onClick={onClickDropdownButton} role="dropdown">
      Dropdown Button
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe all you need to do is stop propagation of the event when you click on the button, therefore you can handle the button click in one event handler and a div click (but not on the button) in the other.

Theres no need to distinguish using a `role` or anything.

```js
const App = () => {

  const onClickDiv = (evt) => {
    if (evt.target.role === 'dropdown') {
      console.warn('clicked on dropdown button. Do something different.')  
    } else {
      console.warn('clicked on div, but not on dropdown button')
    }
    
  }

  const onClickDropdownButton = (evt) => {
    console.log('do stuff with dropdown button')
    evt.stopPropagation();
  }


  return (
    <div style={{ border: 'red solid 1px' }} onClick={onClickDiv}>
        My clickable div
        <div>
          <button onClick={onClickDropdownButton} role="dropdown">Dropdown Button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As there are 2 event handlers. One is on div which implies on the div itself and the child components of that div. So when you click on div,the button [ as its the child component of div ] also triggers its event handler. The simplest way is to add the

`event.stopPropagation()`

on the child component[ button ] not on the parent [ div ]. Actually it stops the triggering of the parent component if both child and parent are having some event handlers. Here's how your event handler should look like :

```
const onClickDropdownButton = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('do stuff with dropdown button')
  }
```

Remember that **event.stopPropagation** always stops the event propagation of parent component, which means you cannot apply **stopPropagation** on parent to stop the child component from triggering its event handler.